# Vue router optional first parameter

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I have a list of routes that can all have an optional first parameter. If the parameter is present in the url, it will change a header I use in my api calls. Everything else remains the same.

Rather than create two sets of routes to handle this, is there a way I can list the first parameter as optional and only define my routes once?

For all routes, there can be an `:environment` param present in the front:

```html
/:environment/:event_identifier/register/pages/:page_uuid
```

or it can be:

```html
/:event_identifier/register/pages/:page_uuid
```

Everything else will remain the same.

```js
let routes = [{
   path: '/:event_identifier/register/pages/:page_uuid',
   name: 'ContentPage',
   component: ContentPage,
   meta: {
      requiresAuth: true,
   },
}, {
   path: '/:event_identifier/register/:pagenum',
   name: 'Register',
   component: Register,
   meta: {
      requiresAuth: true,
   },
}, {
   path: '/:event_identifier',
   name: 'Login',
   component: Login,
   children: [{
      path: '/:event_identifier/:registration_uuid/:pagenum',
      name: 'editRegistration',
      component: Login,
   }]
}]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can declare an optional param like this:

```js
path: '/myroute/:param?'
```

The `?` after `:param` makes it optional, so it will match http://domain/myroute with no param or http://domain/myroute/25 with a param.

But, I would suggest making your optional params *last* on each route. Otherwise, you get some unclear behavior. Imagine you had a route path like this with an optional first param..

```js
path: '/myroute/:optional?/:notoptional'
```

If you visit `http://domain/myroute/25/100`, the `25` would match `:optional?`

But if you visit `http://domain/myroute/25`, the `25` would match `:notoptional`